# How can I tell subprocess to stop escaping my quotes?

Tags: python, vim, subprocess

I'm trying to call Vim using subprocess, and pass it an argument. For example:

```
subprocess.call(['gvim.exe', ''' "+map <F5> :echo 'Hello!'<cr>" '''])
```

This command works on the command line:

```
> gvim.exe "+map <F5> :echo 'Hello!'<cr>"
```

And then I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and it tells me hello.

The subprocess call doesn't work. When I look at the process in task manager, I see that my string is now:

```
"\" +map <F5> :echo 'Hello!'<cr>\""
```

Not at all what I expected, and I don't think it's what Vim expects, either. It *looks* like subprocess is somehow escaping my quotes, but I don't know why.

Is there any way I can get this to work like I expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotes aren't necessary since `subprocess.call` passes the arguments directly to the process without using the shell (unless you set `shell=True`).

So, `subprocess.call(['gvim.exe', "+map <F5> :echo 'Hello!'<cr>"])` will suffice.

Comment: Yes, the problem isn't the escaping (that's only for displaying the string, after all), it's the quotes.